# Optimize distributions for low mean, high variance

Tags: probability-theory, optimization, normal-distribution

Assume a context with $N$ approximately normal distributions where a lower mean implies a 'better' distribution and a high variance or high standard deviation implies a 'better' distribution as well. Unfortunately, it is unknown which of the two weighs heavier and by how much. Does there exist a sound way to go from here to compare the distributions?

Simply calling the distribution with the minimal coefficient of variation $c_v = \sigma/\mu$ the 'best' assumes equal weights, right?

I have seen something on [$\mu-\gamma\sigma$ optimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173246/difference-between-mean-variance-and-worst-case-optimization-for-normal-distribu), but I am not sure when one would use this outside of finance.

Comment: Your question is, basically, "What function $f$ of two variables $(\mu, \sigma)$ which is decreasing in $\mu$ and increasing in $\sigma$ should I use, if I know nothing else?"  And the answer, of course, is that no answer can possibly exist. You need a LOT more information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any knowledge about the weighting, the only thing you can say is the following:

Distribution $F$ is better than distribution $F'$ if and only $F$ has a weakly lower mean *and* a weakly higher variance (one of them strictly) than $F'$.

Comment: Based on this, you can eliminate all "dominated" distributions, which may give you a smaller (or even singleton) set of non-dominated distributions.